# Cannot find address with google geocode API

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am getting my current location (lat, long) from my phone and am able to convert it to correct address. However when I am trying to convert that address back to lat / long  google geocode not able to find it.
An address is:

Baselmattweg 135a
4123 Allschwil
Switzerland

however if i remove 'a' from address line - it comes through. (but it is neiboughour house without 'a')

Any advice?

Comment: Would you mind posting also exact Geocoding API request that demonstrates your issue? I can resolve this address to coordinate with Geocoding API.

Comment: Hmm strange, now i am able to resolve it also.... Just repeating same request i did another day... Starange things happening